# __destruct method is called correctly when implementing Serializable interface in php?

Tags: php, oop, serialization, serializable

I am learning to **[Serializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php)** interface.

**[php.net](http://php.net/)** stated that

> This does not invoke __destruct() or have any other side effect unless
>   programmed inside the method.

which i would like to separate in two parts  according to my sense as:

**1):** **__destruct()** is not called when implementing the **Serializable** interface. But when i use **__destructor()** method as:

```
class myClass implements Serializable{

    public function serialize(){
        return 'I am serialized';
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized){
        //--
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        echo "Hello world";
    }
}

$obj = new myClass();
```

The **__destructor** method works fine and this simply output the following:

```
Hello world
```

**2):** If you need to use **__destruct()** method you need to declare inside the method. But when i declare inside the method as:

```
class myClass implements Serializable{

    public function serialize(){
        return 'I am serialized';
    }

    public function cutomDest(){

        public function __destruct(){
            echo "Hello world";
        }

    }

    public function unserialize($serialized){
        //--
    }
}

$obj = new myClass();
```

It return the following **parser error** as:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in .....
```

Why **[php.net](http://php.net/)** provides wrong documentation or may be i am wrong. Please can anyone teach me about the documentation of **__constructor()** and **__destructor()** in the concept of **Serializable** interface on the following reference page ?

Reference Link http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php.

Comment: Why do you have a public function inside a public function?  Just curious

Comment: Ohk got it, but why php.net says that declare inside the method. see the reference link ...

Comment: @MummyDaddy The documentation doesn't say that you have to declare the `__destruct()` method inside your `unserialize()` method (and you can't as seen by the error message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing the `Serializable` interface has nothing to do with the `__destruct()` method. The `serialize()` method is used to save the object as a string, which can be saved in a file (like the session system do). This step does not trigger the `__destruct()` method since the object still exists and there is most likely a variable reference to that object.

In your first case, the `__destruct()` method is not called by any serialization step. In fact, you don't even serialize your object. However your destructor is called because your script ended and all objects are going to be deleted.

In your second case, you cannot declare methods inside methods, you get the error message in your question. When you are in your `serialize()` method you can call `__destruct()` if you want... or don't. But in regards to the `Serializable` interface the `__destruct()` method is irrelevant.